# Kill a Python.exe process after opening it with PowerShell and Task Scheduler

Tags: python, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I used to run Python scripts with Task Scheduler by executing a .bat file. However, since I'm running this on a Windows VM, this approach would fail after the computer received a Windows update. So I decided to open the scripts differently, I still call the .bat file from Task Scheduler but this file now opens a PowerShell script as admin which calls the Python script.

Here's the .bat file:

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy Unrestricted -File  C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\PsPythonTest\runPythonScript.ps1 -Verb RunAs
```

Here's the PowerShell script:

```
$path = 'C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\PsPythonTest\test.py'

start-process PowerShell -verb runas

python $path
```

The problem that I have is that the Python.exe processes will be left open. I don't want to add a line to the PS script to kill ALL Python instances since I have several tasks running the same way.

How do I have it end the specific Python instance after it's done?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you're goal is to create  backdoor malware to me:)

Comment: what? you know people run Python tasks with Task Scheduler right?

Comment: and my issue is not running the tasks, it's ending the python process after they're done

Comment: Try something more like `$p = Start-Process python -args $path` to grab that new python process as an object, then use `Stop-Process $p` when you want to kill it. You can call powershell directly from a scheduled task, and elevate it within the task as well (run with highest privileges), so I don't think you need the .bat file any more. Is there any reason not to just `exit()` python or `exit` powershell at the end of your script?

Comment: oh I hadn't thought of doing that, let me check, thanks